# Cannot suppress ffmpeg output from ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, ffmpeg

I have ruby on rails app that allows users to upload videos. When a video is added, I have a before_save filter that uses ffmpeg to generate a series of thumbnails. The problem is that ffmpeg is producing tons of console output when I'm saving a video item in the rails console, and when I run my tests.

**My environment:**

- Host Machine: OS X 10.9.2
- Vagrant Box: Ubuntu 10.04.4
- ffmpeg version: SVN-r0.5.9-4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.3
- ruby version: 1.9.3-p194

**Command I'm running:**

```
`ffmpeg -v 0 -ss #{timestamp} -i #{video_file.path} -y -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -s 640*360 #{thumbnail_path}/thumbnail#{i}.jpg`
```

This version of ffmpeg on my VM doesn't seem to care about the "-v 0" option. I've also tried "-loglevel quiet" which causes ffmpeg to error, indicating that the option isn't recognized (both loglevel and v work on my host machine's ffmpeg).

Tried using both exec() and system(), which both caused execution to hang. Tried to redirecting output to a file by doing:

```
`ffmpeg -v 0 -ss #{timestamp} -i #{video_file.path} -y -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -s 640*360 #{thumbnail_path}/thumbnail#{i}.jpg > #{thumbnail_path}/output.txt`
```

Still see output. Next I tried:

```
`ffmpeg -v 0 -ss #{timestamp} -i #{video_file.path} -y -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -s 640*360 #{thumbnail_path}/thumbnail#{i}.jpg &> dev/null`
```

Still seeing output! Finally I tried:

```
$stdout.reopen("#{thumbnail_path}/output.txt", "w")
$stderr.reopen("#{thumbnail_path}/error.txt", "w")
`ffmpeg -v 0 -ss #{timestamp} -i #{video_file.path} -y -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -s 640*360 #{thumbnail_path}/thumbnail#{i}.jpg`
$stdout = STDOUT
$stderr = STDERR
```

Holy cow, that worked! Well, sort of. No more verbose output when running tests, BUT somehow anytime this runs I get kicked out of the rails console.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Comment: Don't use such an ancient `ffmpeg` build and `-loglevel quiet` will work as expected. You can [download a Linux build of `ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) or follow a step-by-step [guide to compile `ffmpeg`](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try :

```
ffmpeg ... >output.txt 2>&1
```

Which insert stdout and stderr in output.txt

Comment: Site note: ``ffmpeg ... /dev/null 2>&1`` does the same trick without saving the output at all (but the above solution is perfect, if you want some kind of logging...)